# `friend` member functions and attributes - gcc vs clang

Tags: c++, attributes, language-lawyer, c++17, friend-function

The following code snippet:

```
struct a
{
    [[nodiscard]] friend int b();
};
```

Produces this error when compiling on `clang++ (trunk 342102)` with `-std=c++17`:

```
<source>:3:5: error: an attribute list cannot appear here
    [[nodiscard]] friend int b();
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Removing `friend` or adding a body to `b` prevents the error.

`g++ (trunk)` compiles the code just fine.

Live example on godbolt: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ttTDuZ

---

- **Is this a `clang++` bug**? Or is there some rule in the Standard that makes this code ill-formed?
- If `clang++` is correct, what's the proper way of marking a `friend` member function as `[[nodiscard]]`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Per [[dcl.attr.grammar]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.attr.grammar#5)

> Each *attribute-specifier-seq* is said to appertain to some entity or statement, identified by the syntactic context where it appears ([stmt.stmt], [dcl.dcl], [dcl.decl]). If an *attribute-specifier-seq* that appertains to some entity or statement contains an *attribute* or *alignment-specifier* that is not allowed to apply to that entity or statement, the program is ill-formed. **If an *attribute-specifier-seq* appertains to a friend declaration, that declaration shall be a definition.** No *attribute-specifier-seq* shall appertain to an explicit instantiation.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

So, clang is right here.  If you have an attribute, the function must have a definition if it is a friend function.

Comment: I see. So this is actually a gcc bug

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Looks that way.  I tried adding `-pedantic` and `-Wextra` to g++'s compile options and I still couldn't get an error or warning out of it.

Answer (score 0):

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99032

The bug is fixed in GCC 12, you now have the following warning.

```
test.cpp:3:30: warning: attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
    3 |     [[nodiscard]] friend int b();
      |                              ^
test.cpp:3:30: note: an attribute that appertains to a friend declaration that is not a definition is ignored
```

The proper way of marking a friend member function as `[[nodiscard]]` is to put the attribute on its definition.

```cpp
struct a
{
    friend int b();
};

[[nodiscard]] int b(){ return 42; }
```